# Using several instances of Fortran functions with allocatable arrays of different size from Python

Tags: python, fortran, cython

I have a complex Fortran code already wrapped with Cython to make it callable from Python. The Fortran code is quite complex and internally allocates many arrays (it's Fortran 90/2003) for all the computations. The size of the arrays is known a priori before calling the wrapper and they are initialized with a call to a initialization subroutine `c_init`. The `pxd` file that I use for the Cython compilation is the following (everything abridged to simplify the post):

```
from numpy cimport ndarray as ar
from numpy import emptyzeros

cdef extern:
    void c_synth(int* mode, double* BInput, [and more parameters...])
    void c_init(int* n)

def _synth(int mode=5, ar[double,ndim=1] BInput=zeros(3)):
    cdef:
        ar[double,ndim=1] out = empty(n, order='F')


    c_synth(&mode, &BInput, <double*> out.data)

def _init(int n=100):
    c_init(&n)
```

The Fortran 90 source code (only the part that is relevant here) reads:

```
module test
use iso_c_binding, only: c_int, c_double
use vars
implicit none

contains
subroutine c_synth(mode, BInput, out) bind(c)
    integer(c_int), intent(in) :: mode
    real(c_double), intent(in), dimension(3) :: BInput
    real(c_double), intent(out), dimension(n) :: out

! A complex calculation that needs many allocatable arrays and
! multifile source code is done here

end subroutine c_synth

subroutine c_init(n) bind(c)
    integer(c_int), intent(in) :: n

! Many allocatable arrays are initialized here plus some data that need to be 
! read only once

end subroutine c_synth
```

Now, I'm in the situation to use the wrapped Fortran code from a Python code for carrying out simultaneous calculations with different sizes of the allocatable arrays, so that `n`in the previous codes will differ from call to call. If I just simply import the Cythonized wrapper from Python and call `_init(n)` several times, the Fortran code will only use the value of `n`from the last call.

As a temporal solution to that, I have already modified my Fortran code to dynamically deallocate/reallocate memory every time I run the code with a different value of `n`, but this makes it not very efficient. I would like to have several instances of the wrapper running in memory, that can be called efficiently from Python without allocating/deallocating memory. Another option I've tried is to monkeypatch the import of the wrapper using `ìmportlib``but all imported modules share the very same Fortran code.

My questions is: is there any way to encapsulate the Fortran code to have several instances running? I have even tried building a Cython class that encapsulates the `_synth` and `_init`methods.

Comment: Well, now you see why global variables are not very scalable for concurency.

Comment: Feels like this might be a candidate for `multiprocessing` - adds overhead of running multiple python interpreters, but otherwise could work - https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Do you know how much the overhead of the allocating/reallocating the memory really is?

Comment: It's not a showstopper, but might be important because I will have to call the Fortran methods millions of times. Currently, I'm working on making the Fortran code more concurrent safe by caching the allocated arrays. I'm coming to the conclusion that this is the only way.